# OpenCV 3.0.0 beta: Error with drawing contours

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, contour, edge-detection, opencv3.0

I was sampling with the OpenCV 3.0.0 beta documentation about getting started with contours, andI encountered multiple errors when trying to use the contour code from the documentation. I have no idea how to fix this, can anyone help me?

Documentation I copied code from:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started

Test picture to apply contour:

http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/image-files/pyramid-base-rectangle.jpg

Line of code that created error:

```
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 3, (0,255,0), 3)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/Documents/Programming/Python/Computer-Vision/OpenCV-Doc/contour-draw.py", line 13, in <module>
    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 3, (0,255,0), 3)
error: /home/anthony/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2160: error: (-215) 0 <= contourIdx && contourIdx < (int)last in function drawContours
```

There is another drawContour function that does not work. Once I comment out the one above and comment in the other function (below), it produces different error.

Line of Code:

```
cnt = contours[4]
cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
```

Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/anthony/Documents/Programming/Python/Computer-Vision/OpenCV-Doc/contour-draw.py", line 15, in 
        cnt = contours[4]
    IndexError: list index out of range

There are two other drawContours functions that are commented out. There is a border one that can successfully create an outline of the picture, but for some reasons, produces an outline of the window.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('rectangle-pink.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Displays the border
#cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)


cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 3, (0,255,0), 3)

#cnt = contours[4]
#cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('Contour Pic', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if it did not find any contours, contours[4] is invalid. you always have to check len(contours) before indexing it.

Comment: I checked the length of the contours and the length turned out to be 2. However, I got the contours[4] from the official OpenCV documentation. What do I do? Is it because of the test image I chose?

Comment: yes, that definitely depends on the image contents. just understand, that `len(contours) - 1` is the largest valid index you can access.

Comment: The picture that the OpenCV documentation used was a rectangle and my photo was a rectangle as well. I kind of thought the program would work on the picture just like how it did in the OpenCV documentation. Any ideas on why this picture would work (http://www.k6-geometric-shapes.com/image-files/pyramid-base-rectangle.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

In my case if I use index as `len(contours)-1`  at some point `len(contours)` becomes zero and the  error is shown:

> indexError: list index out of range

If I use the following code, everything works fine.

```
if len(contours)>0 :
   cnt=contours[len(contours)-1]
   cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
```